Summation of a column using certain conditions
Below is my table:



Part_Key
Part_No
Job_No
Operation_No
Operation_Code
Supplier_Code
Location_Type
Available_Inventory
Location
Summation




6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
10
Stamp - WIP - Std Production
null
null
432
150-01-01-01



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
20
First Wash
null
null
2000
MET-065



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
30
Deburr
null
null
3700
DBR001-006



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
30
Deburr
null
null
4000
MET-065



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
40
Heat Treat
MET-065
Subcontractor
3600
633-01-01-01



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
50
Second Wash
null
null
null
null



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
60
Phos and Oil
PRO-060
Subcontractor
5000
PRO-060



6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
70
Re-pack
null
null
null
null




I need to add a "Summation" column by replacing "Available_Inventory" column in such a way that it satisfies below conditions:

Summation till the rows above.
If inventory is already at the subcontractor of that line, then don't include in the summation.
Don't include the quantity which are already at the Subcontractor level.

(E.g. here the inventory count at Operation_No "40" should be 432+3700 = 4132
and inventory count at Operation_No "60" should be 432+2000+3700+4000+3600 = 13732)
I am able to satisfy first condition by using code:
SELECT
    *, 
    SUM(Available_Inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY Part_No, Job_No 
                                   ORDER BY Operation_No) AS Summation 
FROM #Inventory_Sum

But this does not check condition 2. My biggest drawback here is that I cannot use dynamic query, which restricts me a lot.
This is what I tried:https://dbfiddle.uk/KH9Un8KZ
Can anyone guide me on how can I achieve this task? Or point me to the direction where I can research and find my solution?

Why not add the data you're expected to get calculated in the above table? As they say in Hollywood, show don't tell

@siggemannen, agreed your point sir. However, I have already deleted other 8+ columns from the table and have kept this so that it might help in knowing data. I may be completely wrong as well but this is what I kept as per my understanding :)

Also, isn't this a simple: SUM(CASE WHEN LocalType = 'Sub' THEN 0 ELSE Available_Inventory END). Although, i'm not sure i understand your Subcontractor logic :)

No, because this will still include the quantity which are already at the subcontractor level at operation_No 20 and 30. I don't want that count.

https://dbfiddle.uk/iyaXBcQ not found.

@jarlh, thanks for letting me know. I updated question with a new link.

Then why is Position 60 counting 2000 but not Position 40. Are you just randomly picking the logic or is there some sense in it

@siggemannen The preceding rows are excluded if the Location matches the Supplier_Code of the anchor row and the anchor row is a subcontractor. I'm not sure if that's right or how it makes sense, but I had the same initial reaction as you.

@siggemannen, here I am checking "Supplier_Code" column with the "Location" column.  At op 40 supplier code is MET-065. And operation 20 and 30 have their inventory at location MET-065. Which means that their inventory is already at that subcontractor level. Hence, operation 40 is now only expecting 4132 invenotry. Hoewever, op 60 does not have any inventory yet from the previous operations. Hence, op 60 expects 13732 inventory count

So, do you only expect this summation column to be populated when the row is a subcontractor? (Showing "desired" in the summation column (and calling it "summation (desired)" might be useful.)

Ok, i think i got it.
You want something like this:
WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 10, N'Stamp - WIP - Std Production', NULL, NULL, 432, N'150-01-01-01', NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 20, N'First Wash', NULL, NULL, 2000, N'MET-065', NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 30, N'Deburr', NULL, NULL, 3700, N'DBR001-006', NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 40, N'Deburr', NULL, NULL, 4000, N'MET-065', NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 50, N'Heat Treat', N'MET-065', N'Subcontractor', 3600, N'633-01-01-01', NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 60, N'Second Wash', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 70, N'Phos and Oil', N'PRO-060', N'Subcontractor', 5000, N'PRO-060', NULL)
        ,   (6356413, N'10BAE005-001', 9372, 80, N'Re-pack', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    ) t (Part_Key,Part_No,Job_No,Operation_No,Operation_Code,Supplier_Code,Location_Type,Available_Inventory,Location,Summation)
)
, data2 AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ISNULL(Supplier_code,( -- Get supplier for this row
        SELECT  TOP 1 Supplier_code
        FROM    data d2
        WHERE   d2.Part_key = d.Part_Key
        AND d2.Part_no = d.Part_no
        AND d2.Job_no = d.Job_no
        AND d2.Location_type = 'Subcontractor'
        AND d2.Supplier_code = d.Location
        )) AS Supplier_code_new
    FROM    data d
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    data2 d
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  SUM(Available_Inventory) AS inv
        FROM    data2 prev
        WHERE   prev.Part_key = d.Part_Key
        AND prev.Part_no = d.Part_no
        AND prev.Job_no = d.Job_no
        AND prev.Operation_no <= d.Operation_no -- Summarize preceding rows
        AND (prev.Supplier_Code_new IS NULL OR prev.Supplier_Code_new <> d.Supplier_Code_new) -- But not for which the supplier is current supplier
    ) x

First, i calculate the supplier for all rows by matching Location against a Supplier_code. The idea is to avoid summarizing these rows, except when calculating another supplier.
Don't think aggregated subqueries are possible here, because the values are fluid depending on current row.
Output:



Part_Key
Part_No
Job_No
Operation_No
Operation_Code
Supplier_Code
Location_Type
Available_Inventory
Location
Summation
Supplier_code_new
inv




6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
10
Stamp - WIP - Std Production
NULL
NULL
432
150-01-01-01
NULL
NULL
432


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
20
First Wash
NULL
NULL
2000
MET-065
NULL
MET-065
432


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
30
Deburr
NULL
NULL
3700
DBR001-006
NULL
NULL
4132


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
40
Deburr
NULL
NULL
4000
MET-065
NULL
MET-065
4132


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
50
Heat Treat
MET-065
Subcontractor
3600
633-01-01-01
NULL
MET-065
4132


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
60
Second Wash
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
4132


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
70
Phos and Oil
PRO-060
Subcontractor
5000
PRO-060
NULL
PRO-060
13732


6356413
10BAE005-001
9372
80
Re-pack
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
4132



Note that i had to change operations, because Deburr was duplicated. If you have such duplicates, you need some other way of distinguishing the order of rows besides Operation_no.

I appreciate your answer. Aaron's query worked for me as it is without changing anything so I accepted his answer. Thank you for your help :)

Sure, but both queries are non-deterministic because he uses row_number order by Operation_no which isn't unique. Good luck anyway

I again came here to change my 'accepted answer'. @siggemannen, you are right, your query gives correct summation even when there are multiple locations at the subcontract operation level. I got to know after testing bulk of data since last 3 days. However, I do have one question here, how come your query is faster than Aaron's? To me they both seem quite similar but there is much more performance difference. Asking this for my knowledge as I couldn't figure out.

@AaronBertrand, still thank you for your effort and direction :)

Hard to say to be honest, but he uses RANGE instead of ROWS in the window-SUM, which i think is a little bit slower option, plus a nested window call. I still think his query should be faster, but don't have the real query plans so can't say :) My query uses a CROSS APPLY with a pure descending pattern but his uses a calculated rn selection which might lead to more data scanning

Still trying to understand the logic and guessing that you want an unqualified running sum on rows that aren't labeled as Subcontractor.
As far as I can tell, you can't really do this fully with window functions because they can't be dynamic / conditional upon what's in the anchor row (or its lead-up rows).
So, this not-very-scalable approach might work; at large table sizes, you might be better off using a cursor or doing this in Excel.
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (PARTITION BY Job_No, Part_No 
      ORDER BY Operation_No, Location) /* arbitrary tie-breaker */ 
  FROM #Inventory_Sum
)
SELECT Part_Key, Part_No, Job_No, Operation_No, Operation_Code,
       Supplier_Code, Location_Type, Available_Inventory, Location,
       Summation = COALESCE
                   (
                     y.ContractorSum, 
                     SUM(Available_Inventory) OVER 
                       (PARTITION BY Job_No, Part_No ORDER BY rn)
                   )
FROM x 
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT ContractorSum = SUM(Available_Inventory) 
    FROM x AS x2 
   WHERE x2.Part_No = x.Part_no 
     AND x2.Job_No = x.Job_No
     AND x2.rn < x.rn
     AND x2.Location <> x.Supplier_Code
     AND x.Location_Type = 'Subcontractor'
) AS y
ORDER BY Job_No, Part_No, Operation_No;

I'd show a fiddle, but it's currently broken. You'll have to trust me:



If you only want Summation populated for the Subcontractor rows, then remove the COALESCE() and just use y.ContractorSum.

Thankyou so much for your response and helping me out!! This works exactly as per the requirements which I received. Yes, I 100% agree with your stance of not using windows function for such dynamic situation, however, the platform I am provided to write SQL server query doesn't support dynamic query creation. Also, I am making a UI report for customer so excel options rolls out too. I appreciate your help a lot and wish that one day I try to design query like you :)

You can use a CASE expression to control when Available_Inventory is used or 0 for the sum of a row.
Select *, sum(
  CASE Location_Type 
  WHEN 'Subcontractor' THEN 0 ELSE
    CASE WHEN Location in (SELECT Supplier_Code from #Inventory_Sum WHERE Location_Type='Subcontractor') THEN 0 
    ELSE  Available_Inventory END
  END
  ) OVER (PARTITION BY Part_No, Job_No ORDER BY Operation_No) as Summation
  from #Inventory_Sum

fiddle

Hi. Thank you for your response! But this will still include the quantity which are already at the subcontractor level at operation_No 20 and 30. I don't want that count. As per my condition no. 3.  Inventory count at Operation_No "40" should be 432+3700 = 4132

@Jiji query updated to exclude rows with location = any Subcontractor Supplier_codes

But is it where the location is of any supplier code, or just the one from the anchor row? e.g. imagine there is a location of 'PRO-060' in the first row. Should 432 no longer be included for the sum up to the 5th row?

No not any subcontractor from the location. I just need to exclude the inventory which is already at that "particular" subcontractor. Please see the example in the question.  Operation 40 will indeed have count 4132 but operation 60 will have count 13732.
